# Create a method to calculate Linear Interpolation in C#

Tags: c#, linear-interpolation

I am tasked to create a method to calculate Liner Interpolation where Y is a DateTime value and X is an integer value.  For example, looking at the following values, how to find the values for 7, 8 and 9?

```
Date:       Value:
05/01/2013  5
06/01/2013  7
10/01/2013  9
11/01/2013  1
15/01/2013  7
17/01/2013  2
02/02/2013  8

EDIT: 
int interpMethod(DateTime x0, int y0, DateTime x1, int y1, int x)
{
    return y0 * (x - x1) / (x0 - x1) + y1 * (x - x0) / (x1 - x0);
}
```

Comment: Have you made an effort to solve this yourself?

Comment: -2 but nobody can provide any helpful answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to interpolate points between 2 other points, you need to calculate a rate of change, and then apply that to the distance between the 2 points.

Also, make sure to keep your data types consistent. The data you are showing has doubles, but your method only handles integers. Also, you are asking in the question to put in a double and find the DateTime, but then you are returning an integer?

```
public static DateTime Interpolate(DateTime x0, double y0, DateTime x1, double y1, double target)
{
  //this will be your seconds per y
  double rate = (x1 - x0).TotalSeconds / (y1 - y0);
  //next you have to compute the distance between one of your points and the target point on the known axis
  double yDistance = target - y0;
  //and then return the datetime that goes along with that point
  return x0.AddSeconds(rate * yDistance);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer.  It was a mistake; I just added a function because you asked me for some code.  Anyway, what if I have to use it to iterate thru a list of dates; how can I programmatically enter the two dates?

Comment: wait, do you want to know the Date for a given value, or the value for a given date?

Comment: Nope I just displayed 3 dates but can you suggest me how to loop thru a list of dates?

Comment: right, but you need to know the values of one or the other of those columns in advance for this to make sense. Which column is the known column? Do you start with 5 dates and 3 values? or 5 values and 3 dates?

Comment: Well 3 were just an example, please see my update.  Let say I have 2 columns but about 100 rows.  I can do easy 3 rows but what could be the algorithm with a lot rows, such as 100?

Comment: I manage to make it work, but about the iteration; if I use a while loop while current minutes is less than the next. For example, the current hour = 1 and minute = 50 and the next hour = 2 and minutes = 2?